# Chainload SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX from GRUB2

Tags: boot, grub2, syslinux

Assuming a setup where no portion of SYSLINUX or EXTLINUX has been written to an area of a disk that has not been formatted with a filesystem (e.g., boot sector, BIOS boot partition), how would one go about chainloading SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX from GRUB2?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is effectively "how to boot SYSLINUX or EXTLINUX that has not been fully installed yet?"

I would suggest (tongue-in-cheek) booting FreeDOS, using it to complete the installation of SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX, then rebooting to SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX (by chainloading its partition boot record (PBR) code from GRUB, if GRUB must still be involved at this point)  :-)

Without the PBR code, SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX installation is incomplete. The installer not only writes the PBR code, it also patches some disk block number information directly into the `ldlinux.sys` file, so if you just copy this file from one disk to another, this information will most likely be wrong. If you try and chainload such a copied `ldlinux.sys`, it will most likely just crash for two reasons:

- the patched-in disk block number information is incorrect
- the execution environment from GRUB chainloading may not be exactly the same as from after SYSLINUX PBR code execution.

You can find the PBR code in the [diskboot.inc assembler file](https://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/blob/HEAD:/core/bios/diskboot.inc) of SYSLINUX source package, and the beginning of the `ldlinux.sys` file is built from [diskstart.inc assembler file](https://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/blob/HEAD:/core/bios/diskstart.inc). Even if you don't know how to read assembler code, the comments are informative.

If you're trying to combine a SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX-bootable live Linux distribution or utility into some multi-boot system that uses GRUB, a much easier approach would be to read SYSLINUX's configuration file, and configure GRUB to use the same kernel file, initrd/initramfs file (if applicable), and kernel boot options as SYSLINUX does.

Those are the essential elements of booting the Linux kernel, so unless the booted OS/utility takes the trouble of explicitly checking which bootloader was used, the result should be the exactly the same, no matter if GRUB or SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX was used to boot it. (If there are differences, that's probably a bug.)

Comment: I have to insist on not using GRUB2 to boot my operating system. I have not been able to get it to boot Linux and installation media that use GRUB2 similarly can't boot Linux while ISOLINUX has been able to. What if I "install" SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX to a disk image and launch it from GRUB2 after mounting it?

Comment: If GRUB2 fails to boot Linux on your system while SYSLINUX works, then it suggests there might be a BIOS bug or quirk which SYSLINUX manages to avoid. But then, GRUB might trigger the same bug also when chainloading SYSLINUX. You might need to install SYSLINUX/EXTLINUX as your primary bootloader and forget about GRUB altogether. It may require a bit of customization if your distribution of choice does not properly integrate SYSLINUX in its kernel update procedures, but it should be doable. GRUB-then-SYSLINUX-from-disk-image seems like unnecessary complication.

Comment: The Ubuntu desktop installation media loads just fine, as does the Linux Mint 13.2 desktop installation media. I've been using kexec in a modified Ubuntu ISO to boot my main installation for the time being. I switched over to UEFI mode to load SYSLINUX from GRUB2—which worked—and upon hitting enter after typing `LINUX /vmlinuz`, I received `Loading /vmlinuz... ok` at which point the screen stayed like that without giving me a chance to enter the initrd and boot parameters.

Comment: In other words, you configured the UEFI version of GRUB2 to do something like `chainload syslinux.efi`, right? When in UEFI mode, you might be running into Secure Boot denial: when Secure Boot detects you're trying to load code that is not properly signed, some systems present a warning message, others will just freeze. If possible, try again with Secure Boot disabled.

Comment: My computer's firmware does not have secure boot capability.

Comment: Then it's probably one of the earlier UEFI firmware implementations for x86 architecture, some of which had fairly bad bugs. You have my sympathy. But still, if GRUB fails for you, why you insist on chainloading SYSLINUX from GRUB instead of ditching GRUB completely and just using SYSLINUX?

Comment: Installing Linux Mint, at least, to a blank USB drive without changing any of the default selections actually does get loaded in BIOS mode. If I use a GPT with a BIOS boot partition for GRUB instead, then it just goes back to the firmware boot medium selection screen after going black.

Comment: It's not that GRUB cannot boot. I can get it to load. It's that the screen hangs whenever I try to boot Linux. Aside from installing Linux in BIOS mode to a drive that uses MBR partitioning (I've only verified this with Linux Mint), the only way Linux boots is through ISOLINUX on the installer media.

Comment: That sounds like there might be a problem with Linux display drivers, not with the bootloaders at all.If the framebuffer driver built into the kernel or included in initramfs fails to support the GPU in UEFI mode (EFI framebuffer or native driver), you'll get a black screen. In legacy mode you can get a bit further using VGA text mode, but most distributions will try and switch it into framebuffer mode for sweet splash screen within initramfs... so it really sounds like the BIOS mode failure happens when loading the native driver for GPU.

Comment: The differences between booting with GRUB vs. with SELINUX might be simply because your configuration and/or the boot options the bootloader automatically passes to the kernel are not exactly the same between the two.

Comment: I figured that something like that might have been the case, so I checked `journalctl --list-boots`. None of the times listed match when I booted in UEFI mode.

Comment: Writing to disk (including writing the list of boots!) can only happen after the root filesystem is mounted. The framebuffer driver is usually either built into the kernel or included in initramfs, so any problems with it would naturally happen before mounting the root filesystem.

Comment: That shouldn't matter because the root filesystem is mounted without input from the user.

Comment: Sorry, my point was that the framebuffer driver activation happens before mounting the root filesystem, and so if a malfunctioning FB driver hangs the system when loaded, there cannot be any logs from that boot attempt at all because nothing can be written to the disk at that point yet.